# AttributeError python & Kivy setting property with function

Tags: python, kivy, attributeerror

I'm trying to use a python function (`getText`, see below) to set a property in kivy lang, but im getting an

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'.

This is my code:

kv

```
    BoxLayout:
    padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
    Label:
        text: app.getText()
        halign: "center"
        markup: True
        font_size: root.height / 20
        text_size: self.width, None
        center_y: .5
        on_ref_press: app.on_ref_press(*args)
    BotonAtras:
        on_press: app.root.current = "intro"
```

.py

```
class Calculator(App):
def build(self):
    return kivyfile

def getText(self):
    return ("Hola esta es nuestra aplicacion que fue echa usando [b][ref=kivy]kivy[/ref][/b]\n"
            "grupo esta compuesto por: \n"
            "Ruben Perez \n"
            "Anthony Cambridge \n")
```

Comment: btw the tracebar telling me that the error is in the line " text: app.getText()"

Comment: Please check your code. Removing references to undefined methods yields an example that runs. Cf. [mcve]